# Vuex data-fetching: How to wait for data in different components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch, nuxtjs

---

I'm builing a Web-Shop with Nuxt and Headless Shopify. In a global component (default layout) I'm fetching **allProducts** because they need to be available globally:

**./layouts/default.vue**

```
  async fetch() {
    await this.$store.dispatch('shop/products/setProducts');
  },
```

**./store/products.js**

```
export cost actions = {
  async setProducts(state) {
    const allProducts = await this.$axios.$get('/products');
    state.commit('setProducts', allProducts);
  },
}
```

now, for the ProductDetailComponent, I am using `find` to get a specific product by a slug:

**./components/product-detail.vue**

```
  async fetch() {
    await this.$store.dispatch('shop/products/setCurrentProduct', this.slug).then(() => {
         ....
    });
  },
```

**./store/products.js**

```
export cost actions = {
    // null or empty
    const allProducts = await state.getters.allProducts;
    const result = allProducts.find(x => {
      return slug === x.slug.toString();
    });
    state.commit('setCurrentProduct', result);
}
```

The problem now is, that the **setCurrentProduct** action is triggered, before all the products are loaded. Of course, I could use the **setProducts** in the ProductDetail Component, but I want to avoid calling the action multiple times, as as I said, I need all the products globally. Is there a way, to only trigger the setCurrentProduct action, when the products are finished loading?

Answer (score 1):

Your default layout component doesn’t wait for it’s $fetch call to complete before it starts rendering product-detail.

To solve, you could use the `$fetchState.pending` property inside product-detail (as demonstrated in the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-fetch/)) or you could use `nuxtServerInit` inside your store. This method gets called once on the server, which you can use to populate your store with all product data before any components are rendered. Bear in mind, if you’re pulling in a lot of data this will affect the initial load time of your app. [See the docs.](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action)

I run a web store using nuxt, and I use the nuxtInitServer method to pull in all basic product info (title, summary, price and slug) which I use to power everything except the product-detail page. Within product-detail I use asyncData and the product id from the store to pull more details about the product in.

Comment: hey there. thanks for your comment! I should have mentioned, that I'm using the app in SPA mode, so I won't be able to use nuxtServerInit. But I'll have a look at the $fetchstate.pending method.